# Disruptor park/halt several EventHandlers when exception occurs

Tags: multithreading, event-handling, disruptor-pattern, lmax

We have run into a high CPU usage situation when one of our EventHandlers broke.

Let's say we have several consumers (`EventHanlders`), that are configured to run sequentially over the buffer. If the first EventHandler throws an exception, is there a way to halt (and awake them later) all the other EventHandlers.

What we are doing is putting the failing thread to sleep and after we try to consume the same event again. But we have notice that the other threads continue running and trying to read from the `RingBuffer` even where there are not events to read, raising the CPU behind acceptable levels.

For the moment I'm discarding that this is happening because `WaitStrategy` of the `disruptor`, because under normal conditions is working as expected. We are using a `BlockingWaitStrategy` there.

Some more explanations for the sake of the example

```
INPUT -> [A*] -> [B] -> [C] -> [D]
```

Where INPUT is the event polled from the `RingBuffer` and A, B, C and D are the different EventHandlers that are executing sequentially. A* is the consumer throwing an exception.

What we want to achieve is that when consumer A cannot consume an event (eg. after an exception happens), the OnEvent(...) method of that consumer does not exit but will stay in a loop with regular sleeps trying to consume again the same event when it wakes up. In the meanwhile all the other consumers should be parked or sleeping until A succeeds.

We are using disruptor version 3.3.0.

I have been googling but haven't found a working solution.

Thanks in advance.

Salva.

Answer (score 0):

A college has founded out that this issue could be related with a while loop in the waitFor method in BlockingWaitStrategy.

```
    long availableSequence;
    while((availableSequence = dependentSequence.get()) < sequence) {
        barrier.checkAlert();
    }
```

After several test we have came across this possible solution:

```
var availableSequence: Long = dependentSequence.get()

while(availableSequence < sequence) {
  this.lock.lock()
  this.lock.unlock()
  availableSequence = dependentSequence.get()
}

availableSequence
```

Basically it makes that one thread locks the resource and with that we park momentary all the other consumers avoiding the high usage of CPU.

The second point here is the while condition. This is happening just when the available sequence (that is the sequence of the dependent threads) is below the current sequence number. And that only happens when one thread is holding the lock, for example when A throws the exception.

We still investigating if this is a valid solution, or if it can have some undesired side effects.

Any though about it is welcome.